# Why am I getting h5py error while installing rasa?

Tags: pip, rasa

When I am trying to install rasa ,I am getting following error:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I even upgraded pip.

Please help out!!

Comment: What's your python version? What OS are you on?

Comment: @fkr I am using python version 3.7.3 on windows 10 OS

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663862/cant-install-h5py)?

Comment: @fkr Yes I tried. Still getting the same error!